# How to detect touch while presenting views with gesture recognizers?

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

I have been developing collage like application. In which user can add images, they can scale, move and rotate them. Whenever, I am trying to drag an image which is on top but added earlier than the one behind it, it is not receiving the gesture, rather than the one behind it which is added later gets detected and brought into front. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Write your code, because gesture recognizer no works if you add it before of after, works if this view is touched so Can you write your code for helping you?

Answer (score 0):

I am Using this to remove the gesture in second view...

```
 [imageView1 removeGestureRecognizer:GestureInView2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This are the delegate method of UIGestureRecognizer you can use for your different requirement.

```
touchesBegan:withEvent:
touchesMoved:withEvent:
touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

I didn't understand your issue perfectly, But. 
I think you have to refer for more detail according to your requirement - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. We need to change the index of subviews if you want to make them receive touches. Changing zposition alone will not help to make the view to receive touches.